# How can I automatically convert MySQL DDL to Oracle DDL?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, converters, ddl

I know my question sounds a little bit like a shopping request, but I honestly believe that many people could find it useful.

I've been looking for an automatic tool that converts Data Definition Language from MySQL dialect to Oracle dialect - the other way round would also be fine. I found “SQL Fairy” but I was unable to run it; probably because I'm not familiar with PERL.

Is there any free tool for Windows that converts MySQL DDL to Oracle DDL?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I want to know what are the major production issues one will face while migrating a database(oracle)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153012/i-want-to-know-what-are-the-major-production-issues-one-will-face-while-migratin)

Comment: @APC I don't want to migrate databases. I want to translate the DDL script and run both versions independently.

Comment: Yes but you could copy your MySQL database, migrate the copy and then reverse engineer the Oracle DDL susing DBMS_METEDATA.

Comment: Once I have learned how to migrate databases, there may be a not-so-automatic procedure to eventually get the Oracle scripts. But this doesn't imply that my question is a “duplicate”. Said this, I may consider your suggestion, if no better option arises.

Comment: Why dont you use a migration tool?

Comment: @UğurGümüşhan I don't use a migration tool because I'm not migrating databases. However, if you know about a migration tool with a functionality fitting my purpose, please tell me about it.

Comment: Is this a one time thing or something that you intend to use continuously as an effort to maintain only one DDL script and auto-migrate the other? Do you expect 100% accuracy? I mean, MySQL and Oracle don't support the same feature set, so in many cases an automatic migration is not even theoretically possible.

Comment: @AlvaroRodriguez My desire is to do it continuously. And I don't expect 100% accuracy. In fact, my scripts are quite simple; they create tables with varchars, numbers and auto_increment, and they comment on them.

Answer (score 16):

This site really worked for me and it can convert a bunch of different DDL commands from Oracle, MySql, M$ Sql Server, Sybase and others. http://www.sqlines.com/online.

**Please note the disclaimer below the tool:**

> Note. SQLines Online is a unrestricted version for EVALUATION USE ONLY. For use in projects, please obtain a license.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being able to try it right now. It's been six months since the question arose and I had to move on. I'll take a look to you suggestion when I get back to dialect conversion.

Comment: The tool worked really well for me!

Comment: Excelent tool! It has worked well for me and saved time. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has web pages filled with information on this: [Database Migration Technology](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/migration/index-084442.html) which gives detailed instrctions and help for several different databases including MySql.

The main tool referenced: [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) is free.

Comment: I appreciate your good will in all efforts to help, but my boss doesn't want me to spend more time in this issue. "Just keep both versions of the scripts manually", he has told me.
So, if somebody can tell me about a tool that is known to fulfill my purpose, please tell me about it. But don't tell me "you could find something useful somewhere in this documentation", because I can't afford the time to investigate.
I have already done much investigation and, now, my attention is needed somewhere else. Really sorry about that.