# Mysql Workbench export sql to Oracle 11

Tags: oracle, export, mysql-workbench

I have installed MySQL Workbench with a default database named sakila.

I want to export this database to SQL script for Oracle 11g.

I can export database in SQL with Forward engineer tools but the SQL don't work on Oracle. After searching I found that migration system can migrate to another database system. But I haven't got Oracle in the database system and I want a SQL script.

Do you have an idea?

Comment: MySQL Workbench only works with MySQL servers. The migration module additionally allows to convert data from other RDBMSes to MySQL. This shows that you usually take a tool specific to the target system you want to have data in, which can take other RDBMSes as source, not the other way around.

Comment: Thank you. It's to bad that Oracle Database not be compatible with MySQL Workbench. I like the sectioning of database with color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18384161/1788704) suggests, you can use an online convertor (it works well) : http://www.sqlines.com/online

You copy the SQL create script in it, and you get its Oracle version.

I don't think that a MySQL Workbench plugin exists which does the job. It should be nice to have a script converter plugin in MWB nevertheless...